# Asking for San Francisco font in different size returns a Times New Roman variant on iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uikit

When executing this:

```
let l = UILabel()
let f = l.font!
let f8 = UIFont(name: f.fontName, size: f.pointSize + 8)!
NSLog("\(f.fontName)")
NSLog("\(f8.fontName)")
```

The logs output:

```
.SFUI-Regular
TimesNewRomanPSMT
```

Why am I not getting a San Francisco variant anymore when I ask for the same font but a little bigger? Is this a bug in iOS?

When I do

```
let f8 = f.withSize(f.pointSize + 8)
```

instead I do get .SFUI-Regular.

Comment: I had filed a bug report on this since it was an issue starting with iOS 13. Apple closed it with "Investigation complete - Works as currently designed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `f.familyName` not `f.fontName`

FamilyName: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619033-familyname

FontName: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619024-fontname

Also, fontName from `init(name:size)` must contain full name, including familyName: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619041-init